# TinyMCE 4 toggle toolbar button state

Tags: button, tinymce, toggle, toolbar

What is the simplest way to toggle the state of a toolbar button (like it works with the default bold-button)? I can't "get" to that class i Tinymce that changes the button's look from default to selected. This is my plugin code (simplified):

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myplugin', function (editor) {
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
        text: false,
        image: 'someimage.png',

        onclick: function () {
            /* Toggle this toolbar button state to selected (like with the tinymce bold-button)*/
            /* and of course some other code goes here */
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some fiddling I concluded that the onclick won't do the job here. After hours I ended up with this solution which seams to work nicely in Tinymce 4.x:

```
/* In the timymce > plugins, name your pluginfolder "my_crazy_plugin" and
plugin file as "plugin.min.js" */

/* Your plugin file: plugin.min.js */
tinymce.PluginManager.add('my_crazy_plugin', function(editor) {
   var state;

   /* Actions to do on button click */
   function my_action() {
        state = !state; /* Switching state */
        editor.fire('mybutton', {state: state});

        if (state){
            alert(state); /* Do your true-stuff here */
        }
        else {
            alert(state); /* Do your false-stuff here */
        }
    }

    function toggleState_MyButton() {
        var self = this;
        editor.on('mybutton', function(e) {
            self.active(e.state);
        });
    }

    /* Adding the button & command */
    editor.addCommand('cmd_mybutton', my_action);

    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
        image: 'tinymce/plugins/my_crazy_plugin/img/some16x16icon.png',
        title: 'That Bubble Help text',
        cmd: 'cmd_mybutton',
        onPostRender: toggleState_MyButton
    });
});


/* Your file with the tinymce init section: */
tinymce.init({
    plugins: [
        "my_crazy_plugin"
        ],
    toolbar: "mybutton"
});
```

Comment: This is perfect solution!!

Answer (score 6):

In TinyMCE 4 you can use the simpler stateSelector setting:

```
editor.addButton('SomeButton', {
    text: 'My button',
    stateSelector: '.class-of-node' // or use an element (an id would probably work as well, but I haven't tried it myself)
});
```

Or you can use custom logic using the "nodechange" event

```
editor.addButton('SomeButton', {
    text: 'My button',
    onPostRender: function() {
        var ctrl = this;

        ed.on('NodeChange', function(e) {
            ctrl.active(e.element.nodeName == 'A');
        });
    }
});
```

Reference:
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/migration-guide-from-3.x/#controlstates

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else finds this article for this issue - I found a bit of a simpler way to do it, using the onclick in 4.0.16:

```
/* In the timymce > plugins, name your pluginfolder "my_crazy_plugin" and
plugin file as "plugin.min.js" */

/* Your plugin file: plugin.min.js */
tinymce.PluginManager.add('my_crazy_plugin', function(editor) {
   /* Actions to do on button click */
   function my_action() {
        this.active( !this.active() );
        var state = this.active();

        if (state){
            alert(state); /* Do your true-stuff here */
        }
        else {
            alert(state); /* Do your false-stuff here */
        }
    }

    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
        image: 'tinymce/plugins/my_crazy_plugin/img/some16x16icon.png',
        title: 'That Bubble Help text',
        onclick: my_action
    });
});


/* Your file with the tinymce init section: */
tinymce.init({
    plugins: [
        "my_crazy_plugin"
        ],
    toolbar: "mybutton"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First fire statechange in your command:

```
editor.fire('FullscreenStateChanged', {state: fullscreenState});
```

On button onPostRender change button state:

```
onPostRender: function() {
    var self = this;

    editor.on('FullscreenStateChanged', function(e) {
        self.active(e.state);
    });
}
```